# How to use lotus router with Rack::Builder::map

Tags: ruby, hanami, hanami-router

Is there a way to use map and the (lotus)router namespacing together?  Below is a sample `config.ru` I'm trying to get running as a demo.

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

module Demo

  class Application

    def initialize
      @app = Rack::Builder.new do
        map '/this_works' do
          run  Proc.new {|env| [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["this_works"]]}
        end
        map '/api' do
          run Lotus::Router.new do
            get '/api/', to: ->(env) { [200, {}, ['Welcome to Lotus::Router!']] }
            get '/*', to: ->(env) { [200, {}, ["This is catch all: #{ env['router.params'].inspect }!"]] }
          end
        end
      end
    end

    def call(env)
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end  
end

run Demo::Application.new
```

Comment: Upvoted to get you to your 1500 points asap :)

Comment: @Rahul thx, I notified the project owners and they got the tag added https://github.com/lotus/router/issues/5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is due to the precedence of `do..end` in method calls. In your code the section

```
run Lotus::Router.new do
  get '/api/', to: ->(env) { [200, {}, ['Welcome to Lotus::Router!']] }
  get '/*', to: ->(env) { [200, {}, ["This is catch all: #{ env['router.params'].inspect }!"]] }
end
```

is parsed by Ruby as

```
run(Lotus::Router.new) do
  get '/api/', to: ->(env) { [200, {}, ['Welcome to Lotus::Router!']] }
  get '/*', to: ->(env) { [200, {}, ["This is catch all: #{ env['router.params'].inspect }!"]] }
end
```

In other words the block is passed to `run`, not to `Lotus::Router.new` as you intended, and `run` simply ignores the block.

To fix it you need to ensure the block is associated with the constructor of the router rather than the call to `run`. There are a couple of ways to do this. You could use `{...}` rather than `do...end`, as that has a higher precedence:

```
run Lotus::Router.new {
  #...
}
```

An alternative would be to assign the router to a local variable, and use that as the argument to `run`:

```
router = Lotus::Router.new do
  #...
end
run router
```

Comment: This is the way to go. I've tried locally and can confirm that it works for me.

Comment: Yes that got it working, still not sure the best way to use the lotus router with rack builders map, where multiple routers can be used in a single rack app (this is how we are currently constructing larger sinatra apps)